# jquery get css property of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the background color of the clicked element, but I get the value for: hover. This is my code:

```
$(button).click(function() {
  var bgColor = $(this).css('background-color');
  console.log(bgColor);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing's wrong. You have to hover over an element in order to click it.  I assume from the context of the question that you want the background colour of the default state?

Comment: Yes I want the background colour of the default state

Comment: See the duplicate for more information

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event.target`

```
$(button).click(function(e) {
  var bgColor = $(e.target).css('background-color');
  console.log(bgColor);
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this is upvoted, or what difference you think think it will make, because it won't make any: https://jsfiddle.net/ewrntbnk/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Have a look at this https://jsbin.com/sazoyob/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan And upvote if it is clear now

Comment: All I see in that jsbin is a lot of syntax errors