# jquery get color of clicked bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the background color of the button but after click i get color for :hover. This is my code:

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function()
{
$(this).css('background-color');
}
);
```

I would like to get after clicking the background color for a given button and not the background color for the hover

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery get css property of clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988414/jquery-get-css-property-of-clicked-element)

Answer (score 0):

If it’s not dynamic, just save it at load.

```
var color = $('.btn-primary').css('background-color');
 $('.btn-primary').click( function(){ console.log( color )})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Javascript's className and `this`, and feed it into jQuery to get the CSS:

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function() {
    console.log($('.'+this.className).css('background-color'))
});
```